# How to Ignore default sharing app set by user using Global share Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using Global share intent to share some text as follows;

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Some Text");
        startActivity(intent);
```

The issue is I want to show all the available Apps to share the text with even if the user has set a default app as the image below shows[image]

Comment: A simple solution is metioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511976/is-it-possible-to-hide-some-application-in-intent-appchooser/19512128#19512128

Answer (score 0):

how about using `ShareActionProvider`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Share"
        app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
    ...
</menu>
```

it should not ask for `Just Once` and 'Always` options. You can add this menu in "Menu options" or wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to clear yourself from being the defailt activity using `PackageManager`, but you cannot clear other activities.

So as workaround you can build your own UI for that purpose. For example put in [BottomSheet](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-sheets.html) data which you got that way:

```
PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> infos = manager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
if (infos.size() > 0) {
   //do UI stuff
} else { 
    //No Application can handle your intent 
}
```

It can looks like as:

[image]