# How to get the list of installed Browser Apps in an Android 7.0 running devices programmatically?

Tags: java, android, samsung-mobile-sdk

Before Android 7.0 I was able to retrieve the list of installed browser type applications and it's package name. Then, I upgrade to Android 7.0 and I am only able to retrieve Samsung's Internet browser, but not the other browser type applications such as Chrome .

Device **Samsung Tab A**

This is the code :

```
public static List<String> getListOfBrowser(Context context) {
    List<String> browserPackageName = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> browserList = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo info : browserList) {
            browserPackageName.add(info.activityInfo.packageName);
            Log.e("BrowserList Info ",info.activityInfo.packageName+" total browser"+browserList.size());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("BrowserList Info ",e.getMessage());
    }
    return browserPackageName;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If Android API level >= 23, then you can do like so:

```
List<ResolveInfo> browserList;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.MARSHMALLOW) {
    // gets all
    browserList = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_ALL);
    // only the defaults
    browserList = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
} else {
    browserList = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine. However you should use `PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY` flag -

```
pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

instead of

```
pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
```

Comment: Still give only Samsung browser in list